# Implement OAuth2 to call Azure Rest API from an Azure function

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I am looking for code example in C# for implementing Oauth 2 in order to call the following Azure Rest API: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list from a timer triggered function app.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a function app with http trigger in VS and publish into azure functions.
- To implement OAUTH2 Authentication, Azure function should be registered with Azure active directory.
- Browse to the azure active directory > click on App registrations > find your azure function app application > Authentication > add the API URL and click on Save.
- For the first time of access azure function will show that request is unauthenticated because security token is not passed back as a cookie.
- Instead, posting the token as part of the URL in the address bar will hydrate the principal's identity and claims from the information in the token.

For more detailed information on implementing OAUTH2 Authentication on Azure Functions to call API please refer [here.](https://blog.powney.info/2019/05/add-oauth-implicit-flow-to-azure-function)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that my function will become a timer trigger function. Now it's HTTP triggered for testing purposes.